# operator= override not being used

Tags: c++

I have this assignment:

main.cpp

```
polygon &q = polygonList->top();
polygon p = q;
```

I want to use an operator override to do a deep copy.

polygon.cpp

```
polygon& polygon::operator=(const polygon &obj)
{
    // deep copy here

    return *this;
}
```

polygon.hpp

```
public:
    polygon& polygon::operator=(const polygon &obj);
```

Any idea why its not hitting the overide?

**EDIT** I know its not because my debugger isn't breaking on the return of the override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `p` using a copy constructor.

Instead of `polygon p = q;`, try:

```
polygon p;
p = q;
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why this uses the copy constructor? polygonList->push(*new polygon());

Comment: If it's causing problems, better create a proper copy constructor instead of relying on assignment.

Comment: I have a constructor for my object and a copy constructor. But when I call new polygon() it calls the copy constructor.

Comment: @JeffreyHaines Not without more context. What is polygonList, how is push implemented?  As for `new polygon()` calling the copy constructor... it doesn't. But it may be copied somewhere in `push(...)`.  And you might be leaking memory.

Comment: polygonList is just : std::stack<polygon> * polygonList = new std::stack<polygon>();

Comment: so maybe its calling copy constructor because its a stack of polygon objects.

Comment: @JeffreyHaines Correct... it's copying the object you pushed in. And the original object, since you allocated with `new` but never `delete`d, will leak.

Instead:  `polygonList->push( Polygon() );`

Comment: If using C++11, you could also: `polygonList->emplace()` which should do the same as `push` but construct the Polygon in-place (without copying or moving).